# How to create user profile object in Django REST API?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-users

I have two user profile models, each refers to custom user

**user/models.py**

```py
class Role(models.TextChoices):
    ONE = 'ON', 'One'
    TWO = 'TW', 'Two'


class ProfileOne(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ProfileTwo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


PROFILE_MAP = {
    Role.ONE: ProfileOne,
    Role.TWO: ProfileTwo
}


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
   # fields definition
   role = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Role.choices, null=True)

   objects = CustomUserManager()

   def create_profile(self, role):
        profile = PROFILE_MAP[role](user=self)
        profile.save()

        return profile
```

I need to create profile for user after registration. I've tried to do this in custom user manager's `create_user()` method but it takes no effect.

**user/managers.py**

```py
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, email, role, password, **extra_fields):
        # user initialization
        user.save()
        user.create_profile(role)

        return user
```

What the problem? And is managers suitable for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this action should be performed in adapters.

**users/adapters.py**

```py
class CustomUserAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=False):
        user = super().save_user(request, user, form, commit)
        data = form.cleaned_data
        user.role = data.get('role')
        user.save()
        user.create_profile(user.role)

        return user
```

**project/settings.py**

```py
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'users.adapters.CustomUserAccountAdapter'
```